python Raspberry Pi double occupancy of GPIO
I have a Raspberry Pi with an Display and Buttons (here). And I have a program, that uses the Library (in the appendix) from the Display. The program creates a home screen with dynamic apps. Each app consists of a folder in an "Apps" folder. This contains a 25x25 pixel PNG file, which is required for the home screen, and a .py file, which contains the program code. The newest code from the main program is this;
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import disp # a self-built driver to solve the problems with the double assignment.
import SH1106 # the library, in the appendix
disp.DispSingleton.disp = SH1106.SH1106() # initialize the driver
Disp = disp.DispSingleton()
Read = disp.Read(Disp)

# here I have deleted some lines of code that are not important for the question. It 

def update_display(): # this creates a homescreen
    image = Image.new('1', (Disp.width, Disp.height), "WHITE")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    draw_icons(draw, program_files, current_page, selected_icon)
    Disp.Update(image)

def run_script(script_file):
    import subprocess
    subprocess.run(["python3", script_file])

# Event-Loop
while True:
    update_display()
    Read.update()
    
    if Read.Joystick_Up == 1:
        selected_icon = (selected_icon - 4) % ICONS_PER_PAGE
        if selected_icon < 0:
            selected_icon += ICONS_PER_PAGE
        time.sleep(0.2)
    elif Read.Joystick_Down == 1:
        # as with Read.Joystick_Up, with slightly different values. 
    elif Read.Joystick_Left == 1:
        # as with Read.Joystick_Up, with slightly different values.
    elif Read.Joystick_Right == 1:
        # as with Read.Joystick_Up, with slightly different values.
    elif Read.Joystick_Press == 1:
        program_index = current_page * ICONS_PER_PAGE + selected_icon
        if program_index < len(program_files): # start a app from the homescreen
            print('\033[94m' + "program", program_files[program_index], "started" + '\033[0m')

            # start program and wait
            print("start thread:", program_files[program_index]['script_file'],)
            x = threading.Thread(target=run_script, args=(program_files[program_index]['script_file'],))
            print(x)
            x.start()

            while True:
                if x.run == False:
                    break

            print('\033[94m' + "program", program_files[program_index], "stopped" + '\033[0m')
        time.sleep(0.2)
    elif Read.Key_1 == 1:
        current_page = (current_page - 1) % total_pages
        if current_page < 0:
            current_page += total_pages
        time.sleep(0.2)
    elif Read.Key_2 == 1:
        current_page = (current_page + 1) % total_pages
        time.sleep(0.2)

This is the disp file (disp.py), that should solve the problems with the double assignment;
class DispSingleton(): # Both the program for the homescreen and the running program should access the same data to prevent duplicate use.
    def __init__(self):
        self.disp.Init()
        self.width = self.disp.width
        self.height = self.disp.height

    def Update(self, image):
        self.disp.ShowImage(self.disp.getbuffer(image))

    def Clear(self):
        self.disp.clear()

class Read:
    def __init__(self, disp_instance):
        self.disp_instance = disp_instance
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        self.Joystick_Up = self.disp_instance.disp.RPI.digital_read(self.disp_instance.disp.RPI.GPIO_KEY_UP_PIN)
        self.Joystick_Down = self.disp_instance.disp.RPI.digital_read(self.disp_instance.disp.RPI.GPIO_KEY_DOWN_PIN)
        self.Joystick_Left = self.disp_instance.disp.RPI.digital_read(self.disp_instance.disp.RPI.GPIO_KEY_LEFT_PIN)
        self.Joystick_Right = self.disp_instance.disp.RPI.digital_read(self.disp_instance.disp.RPI.GPIO_KEY_RIGHT_PIN)
        self.Joystick_Press = self.disp_instance.disp.RPI.digital_read(self.disp_instance.disp.RPI.GPIO_KEY_PRESS_PIN)
        self.Key_1 = self.disp_instance.disp.RPI.digital_read(self.disp_instance.disp.RPI.GPIO_KEY1_PIN)
        self.Key_2 = self.disp_instance.disp.RPI.digital_read(self.disp_instance.disp.RPI.GPIO_KEY2_PIN)
        self.Key_3 = self.disp_instance.disp.RPI.digital_read(self.disp_instance.disp.RPI.GPIO_KEY3_PIN)

and a example of the code from a app;
import os
import sys
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
sys.path.append(os.path.expanduser('~/Display'))
import home

Disp = home.Disp
Read = home.Read

image = Image.new('1', (Disp.width, Disp.height), "WHITE")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

class Home:
    def __init__(self):
        print('\033[92m' + "Home initialized" + '\033[0m')
        draw.polygon([(20, 20), (30, 2), (40, 20)], outline=255, fill=0)
        Disp.Update(image)

home = Home() # initialize Home

When I run the program, everything works fine. But when I select an application and click on "Run", this error message appears;
start thread: /home/laurin/Display/Apps/lamps/code.py
<Thread(Thread-2 (run_script), initial)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/pins/pi.py", line 408, in pin
    pin = self.pins[info]
          ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^
KeyError: PinInfo(number=22, name='GPIO25', names=frozenset({'J8:22', '25', 'BOARD22', 'WPI6', 'GPIO25', 25, 'BCM25'}), pull='', row=11, col=2, interfaces=frozenset({'', 'sdio', 'dpi', 'jtag', 'gpio'}))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/laurin/Display/Apps/lamps/code.py", line 7, in <module>
    import home
  File "/home/laurin/Display/home.py", line 145, in <module>
    disp.DispSingleton.disp = SH1106.SH1106()
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/laurin/Display/Lib/SH1106.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.RPI = config.RaspberryPi()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/laurin/Display/Lib/config.py", line 67, in __init__
    self.GPIO_RST_PIN = self.gpio_mode(RST_PIN,self.OUTPUT)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/laurin/Display/Lib/config.py", line 88, in gpio_mode
    return DigitalOutputDevice(Pin,active_high = True,initial_value =False)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/devices.py", line 103, in __call__
    self = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/output_devices.py", line 192, in __init__
    super().__init__(pin, active_high=active_high,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/output_devices.py", line 74, in __init__
    super().__init__(pin, pin_factory=pin_factory)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/mixins.py", line 75, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/devices.py", line 549, in __init__
    pin = self.pin_factory.pin(pin)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/pins/pi.py", line 410, in pin
    pin = self.pin_class(self, info)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/pins/lgpio.py", line 126, in __init__
    lgpio.gpio_claim_input(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lgpio.py", line 755, in gpio_claim_input
    return _u2i(_lgpio._gpio_claim_input(handle&0xffff, lFlags, gpio))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lgpio.py", line 458, in _u2i
    raise error(error_text(v))
lgpio.error: 'GPIO busy'

what I have tried:

Transfer the Disp file when creating the new app.
Both programs pull the data from the same source so that it is only created once. (Singleton, See above)
Restrict access from Home to the GPIO pins while the program is running.

what I have found and tried:

What is the best way of implementing singleton in Python, method 2

How can I solve this problem?
Thank you.
The Librarys:
SH1106.py;
import config
import time
import numpy as np

Device_SPI = config.Device_SPI
Device_I2C = config.Device_I2C

LCD_WIDTH   = 128 #LCD width
LCD_HEIGHT  = 64  #LCD height

class SH1106(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.width = LCD_WIDTH
        self.height = LCD_HEIGHT
        #Initialize DC RST pin
        self.RPI = config.RaspberryPi()
        self._dc = self.RPI.GPIO_DC_PIN
        self._rst = self.RPI.GPIO_RST_PIN
        self.Device = self.RPI.Device


    """    Write register address and data     """
    def command(self, cmd):
        if(self.Device == Device_SPI):
            self.RPI.digital_write(self._dc,False)
            self.RPI.spi_writebyte([cmd])
        else:
            self.RPI.i2c_writebyte(0x00, cmd)

    # def data(self, val):
        # GPIO.output(self._dc, GPIO.HIGH)
        # config.spi_writebyte([val])

    def Restart(self):
        # __init__
        self.width = LCD_WIDTH
        self.height = LCD_HEIGHT
        #Initialize DC RST pin
        self.RPI = config.RaspberryPi()
        self._dc = self.RPI.GPIO_DC_PIN
        self._rst = self.RPI.GPIO_RST_PIN
        self.Device = self.RPI.Device

        # Init
        if (self.RPI.module_init() != 0):
            return -1
        """Initialize dispaly"""    
        self.reset()
        self.command(0xAE);#--turn off oled panel
        self.command(0x02);#---set low column address
        self.command(0x10);#---set high column address
        self.command(0x40);#--set start line address  Set Mapping RAM Display Start Line (0x00~0x3F)
        self.command(0x81);#--set contrast control register
        self.command(0xA0);#--Set SEG/Column Mapping     
        self.command(0xC0);#Set COM/Row Scan Direction   
        self.command(0xA6);#--set normal display
        self.command(0xA8);#--set multiplex ratio(1 to 64)
        self.command(0x3F);#--1/64 duty
        self.command(0xD3);#-set display offset    Shift Mapping RAM Counter (0x00~0x3F)
        self.command(0x00);#-not offset
        self.command(0xd5);#--set display clock divide ratio/oscillator frequency
        self.command(0x80);#--set divide ratio, Set Clock as 100 Frames/Sec
        self.command(0xD9);#--set pre-charge period
        self.command(0xF1);#Set Pre-Charge as 15 Clocks & Discharge as 1 Clock
        self.command(0xDA);#--set com pins hardware configuration
        self.command(0x12);
        self.command(0xDB);#--set vcomh
        self.command(0x40);#Set VCOM Deselect Level
        self.command(0x20);#-Set Page Addressing Mode (0x00/0x01/0x02)
        self.command(0x02);#
        self.command(0xA4);# Disable Entire Display On (0xa4/0xa5)
        self.command(0xA6);# Disable Inverse Display On (0xa6/a7) 
        time.sleep(0.1)
        self.command(0xAF);#--turn on oled panel

    def Init(self):
        if (self.RPI.module_init() != 0):
            return -1
        """Initialize dispaly"""    
        self.reset()
        self.command(0xAE);#--turn off oled panel
        self.command(0x02);#---set low column address
        self.command(0x10);#---set high column address
        self.command(0x40);#--set start line address  Set Mapping RAM Display Start Line (0x00~0x3F)
        self.command(0x81);#--set contrast control register
        self.command(0xA0);#--Set SEG/Column Mapping     
        self.command(0xC0);#Set COM/Row Scan Direction   
        self.command(0xA6);#--set normal display
        self.command(0xA8);#--set multiplex ratio(1 to 64)
        self.command(0x3F);#--1/64 duty
        self.command(0xD3);#-set display offset    Shift Mapping RAM Counter (0x00~0x3F)
        self.command(0x00);#-not offset
        self.command(0xd5);#--set display clock divide ratio/oscillator frequency
        self.command(0x80);#--set divide ratio, Set Clock as 100 Frames/Sec
        self.command(0xD9);#--set pre-charge period
        self.command(0xF1);#Set Pre-Charge as 15 Clocks & Discharge as 1 Clock
        self.command(0xDA);#--set com pins hardware configuration
        self.command(0x12);
        self.command(0xDB);#--set vcomh
        self.command(0x40);#Set VCOM Deselect Level
        self.command(0x20);#-Set Page Addressing Mode (0x00/0x01/0x02)
        self.command(0x02);#
        self.command(0xA4);# Disable Entire Display On (0xa4/0xa5)
        self.command(0xA6);# Disable Inverse Display On (0xa6/a7) 
        time.sleep(0.1)
        self.command(0xAF);#--turn on oled panel
        
   
    def reset(self):
        """Reset the display"""
        self.RPI.digital_write(self._rst,True)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        self.RPI.digital_write(self._rst,False)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        self.RPI.digital_write(self._rst,True)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    
    def getbuffer(self, image):
        # print "bufsiz = ",(self.width/8) * self.height
        buf = [0xFF] * ((self.width//8) * self.height)
        image_monocolor = image.convert('1')
        imwidth, imheight = image_monocolor.size
        pixels = image_monocolor.load()
        # print "imwidth = %d, imheight = %d",imwidth,imheight
        if(imwidth == self.width and imheight == self.height):
            # print ("Vertical")
            for y in range(imheight):
                for x in range(imwidth):
                    # Set the bits for the column of pixels at the current position.
                    if pixels[x, y] == 0:
                        buf[x + (y // 8) * self.width] &= ~(1 << (y % 8))
                        # print x,y,x + (y * self.width)/8,buf[(x + y * self.width) / 8]
                        
        elif(imwidth == self.height and imheight == self.width):
            # print ("Vertical")
            for y in range(imheight):
                for x in range(imwidth):
                    newx = y
                    newy = self.height - x - 1
                    if pixels[x, y] == 0:
                        buf[(newx + (newy // 8 )*self.width) ] &= ~(1 << (y % 8))
        return buf
    
    
    # def ShowImage(self,Image):
        # self.SetWindows()
        # GPIO.output(self._dc, GPIO.HIGH);
        # for i in range(0,self.width * self.height/8):
            # config.spi_writebyte([~Image[i]])
            
    def ShowImage(self, pBuf):
        for page in range(0,8):
            # set page address #
            self.command(0xB0 + page)
            # set low column address #
            self.command(0x02); 
            # set high column address #
            self.command(0x10); 
            # write data #
            # time.sleep(0.01)
            if(self.Device == Device_SPI):
                self.RPI.digital_write(self._dc,True)
            for i in range(0,self.width):#for(int i=0;i<self.width; i++)
                if(self.Device == Device_SPI):
                    self.RPI.spi_writebyte([~pBuf[i+self.width*page]]); 
                else :
                    self.RPI.i2c_writebyte(0x40, ~pBuf[i+self.width*page])
                    
                    

    

    def clear(self):
        """Clear contents of image buffer"""
        _buffer = [0xff]*(self.width * self.height//8)
        self.ShowImage(_buffer) 
            #print "%d",_buffer[i:i+4096]

config.py;
# /*****************************************************************************
# * | File        :   config.py
# * | Author      :   Waveshare team
# * | Function    :   Hardware underlying interface,for Raspberry pi
# * | Info        :
# *----------------
# * | This version:   V1.0
# * | Date        :   2020-06-17
# * | Info        :   
# ******************************************************************************/
# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
# of this software and associated documnetation files (the "Software"), to deal
# in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
# to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
# copies of the Software, and to permit persons to  whom the Software is
# furished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
#
# The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
# all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
#
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
# IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
# FITNESS OR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
# AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
# LIABILITY WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
# OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
# THE SOFTWARE.
#

import time
from smbus import SMBus
import spidev
import ctypes
from gpiozero import *

# Pin definition
RST_PIN         = 25
DC_PIN          = 24

#GPIO define
KEY_UP_PIN     = 6 
KEY_DOWN_PIN   = 19
KEY_LEFT_PIN   = 5
KEY_RIGHT_PIN  = 26
KEY_PRESS_PIN  = 13

KEY1_PIN       = 21
KEY2_PIN       = 20
KEY3_PIN       = 16

Device_SPI = 1
Device_I2C = 0

class RaspberryPi:
    def __init__(self,spi=spidev.SpiDev(0,0),spi_freq=40000000,rst = 27,dc = 25,bl = 18,bl_freq=1000,i2c=None):
        self.INPUT = False
        self.OUTPUT = True
        
        if(Device_SPI == 1):
            self.Device = Device_SPI
            self.spi = spi
        else :
            self.Device = Device_I2C
            self.address = 0x3c
            self.bus = SMBus(1)
        
        self.GPIO_RST_PIN = self.gpio_mode(RST_PIN,self.OUTPUT)
        self.GPIO_DC_PIN = self.gpio_mode(DC_PIN,self.OUTPUT)

        self.GPIO_KEY_UP_PIN     = self.gpio_mode(KEY_UP_PIN,self.INPUT,True,None)
        self.GPIO_KEY_DOWN_PIN   = self.gpio_mode(KEY_DOWN_PIN,self.INPUT,True,None)
        self.GPIO_KEY_LEFT_PIN   = self.gpio_mode(KEY_LEFT_PIN,self.INPUT,True,None)
        self.GPIO_KEY_RIGHT_PIN  = self.gpio_mode(KEY_RIGHT_PIN,self.INPUT,True,None)
        self.GPIO_KEY_PRESS_PIN  = self.gpio_mode(KEY_PRESS_PIN,self.INPUT,True,None)

        self.GPIO_KEY1_PIN       = self.gpio_mode(KEY1_PIN,self.INPUT,True,None)
        self.GPIO_KEY2_PIN       = self.gpio_mode(KEY2_PIN,self.INPUT,True,None)
        self.GPIO_KEY3_PIN       = self.gpio_mode(KEY3_PIN,self.INPUT,True,None)

        #self.Disable_All_PIN    


    def delay_ms(self,delaytime):
        time.sleep(delaytime / 1000.0)

    def gpio_mode(self,Pin,Mode,pull_up = None,active_state = True):
        if Mode:
            return DigitalOutputDevice(Pin,active_high = True,initial_value =False)
        else:
            return DigitalInputDevice(Pin,pull_up=pull_up,active_state=active_state)


    def gpio_pwm(self,Pin):
        return PWMOutputDevice(Pin,frequency = 10000)

    def set_pwm_Duty_cycle(self,Pin,value):
        Pin.value = value

    def digital_write(self, Pin, value):
        if value:
            Pin.on()
        else:
            Pin.off()

    def digital_read(self, Pin):
        return Pin.value

    def spi_writebyte(self,data):
        self.spi.writebytes([data[0]])

    def i2c_writebyte(self,reg, value):
        self.bus.write_byte_data(self.address, reg, value)
    
    def module_init(self): 
        self.digital_write(self.GPIO_RST_PIN,False)
        if(self.Device == Device_SPI):
            self.spi.max_speed_hz = 1000000
            self.spi.mode = 0b11  
        # CS_PIN.off()
        self.digital_write(self.GPIO_DC_PIN,False)
        return 0

    def module_exit(self):
        if(self.Device == Device_SPI):
            self.spi.close()
        else :
            self.bus.close()
        self.digital_write(self.GPIO_RST_PIN,False)
        self.digital_write(self.GPIO_DC_PIN,False)

### END OF FILE ###


Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Using subprocess to run the python3 with parameters is not how one should do in Python.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

You seem to think that the singleton protects you from requesting the same resources twice.  That is only true within one program. If you run two instances of the program (one for the homescreen and one for the app) then both will have their own singleton, and the second one will fail to request resources already held by the other.
